# How to re-pivot data in bash?

Tags: bash, csv

I know I can do this in python, but I was wondering if there is a ready made bash utility for this.

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
item1 field1 value1
item1 field2 value2
item1 field3 value3    
item2 field1 value4
item2 field2 value5
item2 field3 value6
```

I want to turn this into:

```
item_number field1 field2 field3
item1       value1 value2 value3
item2       value4 value5 value6
```

Comment: "ready made"? no. Possible to code in bash? Yes, with bash version 4+ (for associative arrays).

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple with the great Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc)

```
mlr --inidx --ifs ' ' --repifs --opprint reshape -s 2,3 then label item_number inputFile
```

gives you

```
item_number field1 field2 field3
item1       value1 value2 value3
item2       value4 value5 value6
```

It's opensource and multiplatform: https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/tag/5.4.0